# How to set custom data object to timepicker in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use this [Angular timepicker plugin](https://github.com/Recras/angular-jquery-timepicker). It does input field with times.
How I can set my times items for `ng-model`?
For example I need to display the following times by AJAX:

```
11:00
14:00
```

Comment: Can you show code that you've already tried? or plunkr would be best.

Comment: I tried to set date object to ng-model in input like as: `$model = {new Date()}`.